# Java questions on equals and compareTo method

Tags: java, linked-list, equals, compareto

Hi I'm very new to Java and have this problem with 2 methods operating on linkedList.

The find function I have wrote always return false. 
The find method is to take a type E element as argument, and returns true if the item is in the linked List, or false otherwise.

The max method is to return the maximum element(Longest String in this case) in the list if the list is not empty, or null if empty list. The comparison has to be done by compareTo().
The max I have wrote is only looking at the first letter of every element(string).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
  public boolean find(E e){
      LinkedListTest<E>.Node node = null;
    Node current =node;
      while (current != null){
          if (current.equals(e)){
              return true;
          }
          else{
              current=current.next;
          }
      }
      return false;
  }
  public E max(){
      Iterator<E> iterator=iterator();
      E max = iterator.next();
      while (iterator.hasNext())
      {  
         E next = iterator.next();
         if (max.compareTo(next) > 0) 
            max = next;
      }
    return max;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `find` always returns false because you initialize `node` and `current` to null, so the loop is never entered. In addition, you should compare e to the item, not to the Node.

It should probably be:

```
public boolean find(E e){
    Node current = head;
    while (current != null){
        if (current.item.equals(e)){
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! When calling the function, am I correct by treating it  a String? System.out.println(lst.find("Mango")); Because my concern is, the parameter is E, but I'm calling the String "Mango".

Comment: @Robert Yes, you are correct, since you created a `LinkedListTest<String>`, so E is String in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm still puzzled over the max function.

Comment: @Robert The only problem I see in your max method is that it would throw an exception if the list is empty, since you call the first next() before checking hasNext(). What did you get as the output of max? You should get Plum. Did you expect something else?

Comment: I meant to find the longest String element, which should return Orange. So  I guess it's wrong of me to use compareTo? as it's done lexicographically. Any suggestions on how to find the longest String element?

Comment: @Robert You could pas a `Comparator<E>` to either the constructor of your LinkedListTest class or directly to the max method. Then you can use the compare method of that interface. If you pass a Comparator, you get to implement the compare method, which in the case of Strings can be `public int compare(String s1,String s2) {return s1.length()-s2.length();}` (in addition to some null checks).